# SkyCoord distance throws KeyError: 0

Tags: python, astropy

```
# print(df['parallax'].min())
# 724097.8971232784
# print(df['parallax'].max())
# 767397.7874147035

# Convert the RA, Dec, and parallax to 3D Cartesian coordinates
c = SkyCoord(ra=df['ra']*u.deg, dec=df['dec']*u.deg, distance=df['parallax']*u.pc, frame='icrs')
```

I'm trying to convert my retrieved data to cartesian coordinates using SkyCord but the execution throws a KeyError: 0

I've been able to narrow down the source of the error to the distance parameter.
The distance values in my data set are in the range of 724097.8971232784 to 767397.7874147035 and I've made sure that there aren't any NaN entries. But it looks to me as though SkyCoord has an issue with my distance values anyway.

Any ideas as to how to fix this problem are much appreciated.

I'm using astropy 5.1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I've been able to get rid of this error by doing the conversion to Quantity object beforehand and defining dtype as float64 as follows:

```
parallax = u.Quantity(df['parallax'], unit='pc', dtype='float64')
# Convert the RA, Dec, and parallax to 3D Cartesian coordinates
c = SkyCoord(ra=df['ra']*u.deg, dec=df['dec']*u.deg, distance=parallax*u.pc, frame='icrs')
```